# Match index from DataFrame A to col number of DataFrame B

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

In short, how do you match the index # of a DataFrame to a column number of a separate dataframe?

---

I am trying to do this ^ because DataFrame A has a list of portfolios, the weights of each fund in that portfolio, and corresponding metrics (returns, volatility, etc.) and DataFrame B has the daily cumulative returns of each one of the portfolios outlined in DataFrame A. See a snippit of each below...

DataFrame A

```
   PSGAX  MACGX  CPOAX  MSFBX  ...  VINIX  Returns  Volatility  Sharpe Ratio
3   0.34  0.000    0.0  0.272  ...   0.15    0.130       0.097         1.031
2   0.00  0.000    0.0  0.000  ...   0.15    0.088       0.081         0.716
0   0.00  0.612    0.0  0.068  ...   0.15    0.097       0.145         0.462
1   0.00  0.000    0.0  0.000  ...   0.15    0.075       0.155         0.290
```

DataFrame B

```
                       0             1             2             3
Date                                                              
2014-10-28      0.000000      0.000000      0.000000      0.000000
2014-10-29      0.000000      0.000000      0.000000      0.000000
2014-10-30  10064.705138   8326.212482   7397.407442  10071.353993
2014-10-31  10201.869986   8192.885999   7445.309580  10188.468770
2014-11-03  10184.040340   8272.103934   7447.680945  10148.797890
2014-11-04  10167.215094   8139.644423   7445.886503  10167.811613
2014-11-05  10070.419821   8009.376679   7467.766390  10212.995583
2014-11-06  10169.867499   8145.063117   7479.148990  10237.356046
2014-11-07  10157.369105   8388.279532   7479.980665  10201.779090
2014-11-10  10203.803157   8195.931455   7489.981792  10242.488798
2014-11-11  10215.416983   8344.922782   7488.531872  10274.749752
2014-11-12  10241.533449   8329.066481   7485.325991  10289.547296
......................................................................
2019-10-21  15202.051493  12506.156321  14809.452786  18902.729085
2019-10-22  14895.540671  12469.054343  14759.975126  18747.214047
2019-10-23  14921.969830  12519.182867  14765.817287  18799.355736
2019-10-24  15018.618443  12670.871976  14810.664506  18882.446150
2019-10-25  15104.878608  12723.237235  14833.833249  18928.260160
```

As you can see, DataFrame A is sorted on Sharpe Ratio, which is why the indexes are not in numerical order. In this case, DataFrame B's 3rd column houses the cumulative daily returns of the 'best' portfolio as shown by DataFrame A.

**1) So how do I call that 'best' column (3rd column in this case) of DataFrame B knowing it is the first row in DataFrame A with an index value that matches its location in DataFrame B?**

**2) If I wanted to call the 4th 'best' portfolio in a similar manner, how would that be done?**

Comment: So are you looking for a transpose, `df_A.T`?

Comment: Are you looking to view the column of `df_b` based on the index of `df_a`? Something like: `df_b[df_a.index.values[0]]` to view the best and something like `df_b[df_a.index.values[3]]` to view the fourth best

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Thanks @Chris